# How to stop dojo from scrolling to required input

Tags: forms, dojo, scroll, widget, textinput

I have a long webpage with a form at the bottom. The form has several inputs and one of them is required="true". After the parser parses all the inputs and dojoifies them, it scrolls down to that required field - which of cours is not what I want the visitors to see first since the important things are at the top of the page. This scrolling behaviour might be smart in some cases - but in my case it totally sucks.

How do I tell dojo to stop scrolling to the required text input?

Thanks to all the dojo gurus out there!

Answer (score 1):

The base widget `dijit.form._FormWidget` has `scrollOnFocus` property that is inherited by descendant widgets.
Set it to `false`. It helped me to prevent scrolling to buttons.

---

That won't work because the `dijit.Form` contains the logic that focuses the first invalid field.
The quickest solution I can think of is adding a patch that would override `validate` method of `dijit.form._FormMixin`. You'll need to require the patch on those pages where you want new behavior.

```
dojo.provide("your.namespace.FormPatch");
dojo.extend(dijit.form._FormMixin, {
    validate: function() { /* your implementation here */ }
});
```

You can also define a new widget that would inherit from `dijit.Form`.

Comment: that sounds good - but how exactly do i do that?
i have this now:

    dojo.byId("signupForm").scrollOnFocus = false;
    dojo.byId("signupForm").setAttribute("scrollOnFocus", false);
    dijit.byId("signupForm").attr("scrollOnFocus", false);
    signupForm.attr("scrollOnFocus", "false");
    signupForm.validate();

that doesnt do it :(

Comment: You should do this for each input widget in the form. For example, dijit.byId("textInput1").scrollOnFocus = false;

Comment: Sorry but that doesn' seem to work either :( I have tried everything I could think of to set "scrollOnFocus" to false on the form AND the inputs... Is there a way to stop the first required field in a form to focus upon validation? Or any other way to show the required fields yellow/with warning icon WITHOUT validating the form?

Comment: You're right. Please see the update. You can copy the original validate method to your patch and try to make the modifications.